# Set in option setting to never make matrix slices become vectors

Tags: r

I usually find myself trying to make matrices be still matrices when I slice them.

I.e.,

```
xyz = matrix(1:8, 2, 4)
ncol(xyz[1,])
ncol(xyz[1,,drop=F])
```

Is there anyway to make that the slicing of xyz is always a matrix, such that the default is drop=F, for all slicing operations in my code?